# How to update table with summarized view from a config table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table A with data associated for an account for each month and there could be multiple entries in each month with following data as shown in snippet.

[image]

**Expected transformed table**

I want to generate table something like below as shown in below snippet. Idea is that for each distinct account_id in table A (configuration) , would like to generate a summary table such that each account_id will have a summarized entry for each month in the calendar year, latest/ last entry of account_id for that month decides whether the account is active or not. For an account with no entry for a particular month the value of ACTIVE column would be empty.

[image]

Any inputs on how to achieve this would be much appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: Which database system do you use (e.g, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle)? Date functions can differ between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that nobody has answered this yet, I have given it a shot. On the other hand, I haven't used Snowflake nor can I find a place I can try my code with it (similar to db<>fiddle sites) so you may need to modify this to fit conventions for Snowflake.

I have, however, tried to make this as simple and generic as possible. If there are any minor issues please convert it to what you need.

First things first - I created the base data set, as well as a numbers table (called `Num`) which has the values 0 to 11. You can use any other way to generate the numbers; I just used this as a fairly generic approach to create the list of months.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ("Time" datetime, Account_Id varchar(3), Active varchar(1))
INSERT INTO TableA ("Time", Account_Id, Active) VALUES
('2020-02-25 00:00:30', '111', 'T'),
('2020-02-15 00:10:30', '112', 'T'),
('2020-03-17 10:00:30', '111', 'F'),
('2020-04-09 01:00:24', '111', 'T'),
('2020-05-18 01:00:22', '112', 'F'),
('2020-01-01 11:11:11', '111', 'T'),
('2020-02-28 10:00:00', '111', 'F'),
('2020-05-28 01:00:22', '112', 'F');

CREATE TABLE Nums (n int);
INSERT INTO Nums (n) VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11);
```

The next step is involved three steps: 2 CTEs, and the SELECT statement that draws those together.

- The first CTE `All_Account_Months` creates all the rows you need - one row per Account_Id per month.
- The second CTE uses a window function to work out the last `Active` value for a given Account_ID and month.
- The SELECT statement then does a LEFT JOIN between these - starting with the first CTE, then adding the extra column `Active` to it.

For this, I wrote it in SQL Server (t-sql) - I have a [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00065c1b8606d8357b76727e0f818df1) with the run. However, below, I have tried to convert it to Snowflake based on the documentation (e.g., changing column identifiers to double quotes, changing the FORMAT to get the month name to TO_VARCHAR). I'm sorry though - I don't have a place to test it.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2020-01-01 00:00:00';

WITH All_Account_Months AS
    (SELECT A.Account_ID,
            TO_VARCHAR(DATEADD(month, N.n, @StartDate), 'MMMM yyyy') AS "Month"
     FROM   Nums N
            CROSS JOIN
                (SELECT DISTINCT Account_ID
                    FROM TableA
                ) A
    ),
Latest_Active_Values AS
    (SELECT * 
     FROM   (SELECT *,
                TO_VARCHAR(Asub."Time", 'MMMM yyyy') AS "Month",
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Asub.Account_ID, YEAR(Asub."Time"), MONTH(Asub."Time") ORDER BY Asub."Time" DESC) AS rn
            FROM TableA Asub
            ) AS A
     WHERE  A.rn = 1
    )
SELECT  AAM.Account_ID, AAM.Month, LAV.Active
FROM    All_Account_Months AAM
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Latest_Active_values LAV
            ON AAM.Account_Id = LAV.Account_Id
            AND AAM."Month" = LAV."Month";
```

Results are as follows - the same as yours except I think you typo'ed March for 111 - it should be F not T?

```
Account_ID  Month           Active
111         January 2020    T
111         February 2020   F
111         March 2020      F
111         April 2020      T
111         May 2020        NULL
111         June 2020       NULL
111         July 2020       NULL
111         August 2020     NULL
111         September 2020  NULL
111         October 2020    NULL
111         November 2020   NULL
111         December 2020   NULL
112         January 2020    NULL
112         February 2020   T
112         March 2020      NULL
112         April 2020      NULL
112         May 2020        F
112         June 2020       NULL
112         July 2020       NULL
112         August 2020     NULL
112         September 2020  NULL
112         October 2020    NULL
112         November 2020   NULL
112         December 2020   NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can generate dates in Snowflake using:

```
select dateadd(month, seq4, '2020-01-01') as dte
from table (generator(rowcount => 12))
```

So, the idea is to do the following:

- Generate the dates you want.
- Cross join with all the accounts to get the rows.
- Do some fiddling to get the last status for each month for each account.
- Join that in.
- Finally, if a month is missing a status, but there is a status afterwards, you can use `lag(ignore nulls)` to get the result.

So:

```
with months as (
      select dateadd(month, seq4, '2020-01-01') as mon
      from table (generator(rowcount => 12))
     )
select a.account_id, m.mon,
       coalesce(t.active,
                lag(t.active ignore nulls) over (partition by a.account_id order by m.mon)
               ) as active
from (select distinct account_id from t) a cross join
     months m left join
     (select mon, account_id,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then active end) as active
      from (select t.*, date_trunc('month', time) as mon,
                   row_number() over (partition by account_id, date_trunc('month', time) order by time desc) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
     on t.mon = m.mon and t.account_id = a.account_id
```